# How to execute Hive hql files from java?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I understand I can do it by parsing the hql file, extracting individual queries and executing each query separately, but I want to know whether there's a better and more graceful way to run a command like:

```
hive -f "queries.hql"
```

through java. One way would be using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, but I want to do this the proper jdbc way, using HiveServer2 - if that's possible.

If it's possible, an example would be very much appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

refer to the link
Here they are using Hive Cli Driver
I have used this to process HQL files
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver

```
public HiveExec(HdfsSinkConnectorConfig config) {
    hiveConf = new HiveConf();
    String hiveConfDir = config.getString(HdfsSinkConnectorConfig.HIVE_CONF_DIR_CONFIG);
    hiveConf.addResource(new Path(hiveConfDir, "hive-site.xml"));
    SessionState.start(new CliSessionState(hiveConf));
    cliDriver = new CliDriver();
}
```